# Android : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, gridview

I'm working with a gridView which has 50 items all with image and title. The problem is that I tested the gridView with 5 items, and then, I put the all items I have, and now it errors and says: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError . How to solve it? Thanks a lot !

**Galerie.java:**

```
package com.descoper.rom;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Galerie extends Activity {
    GridView gridView;
    ArrayList<Item> gridArray = new ArrayList<Item>();
    GalerieAdapter customGridAdapter;
    private Dialog dialog;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.galerie);

        // set grid view item
        Bitmap casapoporului = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                this.getResources(), R.drawable.casapoporului);
        Bitmap transfagarasan = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                this.getResources(), R.drawable.transfagarasan);
        Bitmap transalpina = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
                R.drawable.transalpina);
        Bitmap colibita = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
                R.drawable.colibita);
        Bitmap balealac = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
                R.drawable.balealac);
        Bitmap barajulsiriu = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
                R.drawable.barajulsiriu);
        Bitmap bisericadesublac = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                this.getResources(), R.drawable.bisericadesublac);
        Bitmap canionulscari = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                this.getResources(), R.drawable.canionulscari);
        Bitmap cascadacailor = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                this.getResources(), R.drawable.cascadacailor);
        Bitmap cascadaciucas = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                this.getResources(), R.drawable.cascadaciucas);
        Bitmap castelulbran = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
                R.drawable.castelulbran);
        Bitmap castelulcorvinilor = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                this.getResources(), R.drawable.castelulcorvinilor);
        Bitmap castelulkaroly = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                this.getResources(), R.drawable.castelulkaroly);
        Bitmap castelulpeles = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                this.getResources(), R.drawable.castelulpeles);
        Bitmap castelulsturdza = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                this.getResources(), R.drawable.castelulsturdza);
        Bitmap castrulroman = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
                R.drawable.castrulroman);
        Bitmap cazaneledunarii = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                this.getResources(), R.drawable.cazaneledunarii);
        Bitmap cazinoulconstanta = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                this.getResources(), R.drawable.cazinoulconstanta);
        Bitmap cetateabastionara = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                this.getResources(), R.drawable.cetateabastionara);
        Bitmap cetateafagaras = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                this.getResources(), R.drawable.cetateafagaras);
        Bitmap cetateaprejmer = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                this.getResources(), R.drawable.cetateaprejmer);
        Bitmap cheilebicazului = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                this.getResources(), R.drawable.cheilebicazului);
        Bitmap cimitirulsapanta = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                this.getResources(), R.drawable.cimitirulsapanta);
        Bitmap deltadunarii = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
                R.drawable.deltadunarii);
        Bitmap epavacostinesti = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                this.getResources(), R.drawable.epavacostinesti);
        Bitmap focurilevii = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
                R.drawable.focurilevii);
        Bitmap hanulancutei = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
                R.drawable.hanulancutei);
        Bitmap insulaovidiu = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
                R.drawable.insulaovidiu);
        Bitmap laculalbastru = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                this.getResources(), R.drawable.laculalbastru);
        Bitmap laculana = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
                R.drawable.laculana);
        Bitmap laculbeului = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
                R.drawable.laculbeului);
        Bitmap laculbucura = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
                R.drawable.laculbucura);
        Bitmap laculcapra = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
                R.drawable.laculcapra);
        Bitmap laculrosu = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
                R.drawable.laculrosu);
        Bitmap laculvidra = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
                R.drawable.laculvidra);
        Bitmap laculvulturilor = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                this.getResources(), R.drawable.laculvulturilor);
        Bitmap mocanita = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
                R.drawable.mocanita);
        Bitmap parculcraiova = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                this.getResources(), R.drawable.parculcraiova);
        Bitmap pesteraghetarul = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                this.getResources(), R.drawable.pesteraghetarul);
        Bitmap pesteraursilor = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                this.getResources(), R.drawable.pesteraursilor);
        Bitmap piatabrasov = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
                R.drawable.piatabrasov);
        Bitmap poduldumnezeu = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                this.getResources(), R.drawable.poduldumnezeu);
        Bitmap salinapraid = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
                R.drawable.salinapraid);
        Bitmap salinaturda = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
                R.drawable.salinaturda);
        Bitmap sarmisegetuza = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                this.getResources(), R.drawable.sarmisegetuzaregia);
        Bitmap sfinxulbucegi = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                this.getResources(), R.drawable.sfinxulbucegi);
        Bitmap sibiu = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
                R.drawable.sibiu);
        Bitmap vulcaniinoroiosi = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                this.getResources(), R.drawable.vulcaniinoroiosi);

        gridArray.add(new Item(casapoporului, "Casa poporului"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(transfagarasan, "Transfagarasan"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(transalpina, "Transalpina"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(colibita, "Colibita"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(balealac, "Balea Lac"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(barajulsiriu, "Barajul Siriu"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(bisericadesublac, "Biserica de sub lac"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(canionulscari, "Canionul Sapte Scari"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(cascadacailor, "Cascada Cailor"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(cascadaciucas, "Cascada Ciucas"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(castelulbran, "Castelul Bran"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(castelulcorvinilor, "Castelul Corvinilor"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(castelulkaroly, "Castelul Karoly"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(castelulpeles, "Castelul Peles"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(castelulsturdza, "Castelul Sturdza"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(castrulroman, "Castrul Roman"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(cazaneledunarii, "Cazanele Dunarii"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(cazinoulconstanta, "Cazinoul din Constanta"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(cetateabastionara, "Cetatea bastionara Alba Carolina"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(cetateafagaras, "Cetatea Fagarasului"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(cetateaprejmer, "Biserica fortificata din Prejmer"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(cheilebicazului, "Cheile Bicazului"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(cimitirulsapanta, "Cimitirul Vesel din Sapanta"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(deltadunarii, "Delta Dunarii"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(epavacostinesti, "Epava navei Evangelia de la Costinesti"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(focurilevii, "Focurile Vii din Lopatari"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(hanulancutei, "Hanul Ancutei"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(insulaovidiu, "Insula Ovidiu"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(laculalbastru, "Lacul Albastru"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(laculana, "Lacul Sfanta Ana"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(laculbeului, "Lacul Ochiul Beiului"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(laculbucura, "Lacul Bucura"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(laculcapra, "Lacul Capra"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(laculrosu, "Lacul Rosu"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(laculvidra, "Lacul Vidra"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(laculvulturilor, "Lacul Vulturilor"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(mocanita, "Mocanita din Viseu de Sus"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(parculcraiova, "Parcul Nicolae Romanescu"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(pesteraghetarul, "Pestera Scarisoara"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(pesteraursilor, "Pestera Ursilor"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(piatabrasov, "Piata Sfatului din Brasov"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(poduldumnezeu, "Podul lui Dumnezeu"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(salinapraid, "Salina Praid"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(salinaturda, "Salina Turda"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(sarmisegetuza, "Sarmizegetusa Regia"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(sfinxulbucegi, "Sfinxul din Bucegi"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(sibiu, "Piata Mare din Sibiu"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(vulcaniinoroiosi, "Vulcanii Noroiosi"));



        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
        customGridAdapter = new GalerieAdapter(this, R.layout.galerie_row,
                gridArray);
        gridView.setAdapter((ListAdapter) customGridAdapter);
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                if (position == 0) {
                    dialog = new Dialog(Galerie.this);
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog1);
                    dialog.setTitle("Romania");

                    TextView text = (TextView) dialog
                            .findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                    text.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
                    Button btnSave = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button1);

                    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            dialog.dismiss();
                            finish();

                        }
                    });
                    dialog.show();
                }

                if (position == 1) {
                    Toast.makeText(Galerie.this, "APASATAAAAAAA" + position,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                if (position == 2) {
                    Toast.makeText(Galerie.this, "APASATAAAAAAA" + position,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**logcat:**

```
05-05 09:43:40.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1149): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-05 09:43:40.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1149): Process: com.descoper.rom, PID: 1149
05-05 09:43:40.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1149): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
05-05 09:43:40.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
05-05 09:43:40.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:587)
05-05 09:43:40.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:422)
05-05 09:43:40.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:445)
05-05 09:43:40.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:475)
05-05 09:43:40.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at com.descoper.rom.Galerie.onCreate(Galerie.java:60)
05-05 09:43:40.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
05-05 09:43:40.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-05 09:43:40.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
05-05 09:43:40.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
05-05 09:43:40.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-05 09:43:40.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
05-05 09:43:40.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-05 09:43:40.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-05 09:43:40.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-05 09:43:40.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-05 09:43:40.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-05 09:43:40.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-05 09:43:40.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-05 09:43:40.562: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Line 60-61:**

```
Bitmap castelulsturdza = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
            this.getResources(), R.drawable.castelulsturdza);
```

**GalerieAdapter.java:**

```
package com.descoper.rom;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class GalerieAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {
    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    ArrayList<Item> data = new ArrayList<Item>();

    public GalerieAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
            ArrayList<Item> data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        RecordHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new RecordHolder();
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_text);
            holder.imageItem = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (RecordHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        Item item = data.get(position);
        holder.txtTitle.setText(item.getTitle());
        holder.imageItem.setImageBitmap(item.getImage());
        return row;

    }

    static class RecordHolder {
        TextView txtTitle;
        ImageView imageItem;

    }
}
```

Comment: don't you think that's a lot of bitmaps? how big are they anyway? (hard to pinpoint a OOME without any information of the memory used...)

Comment: I know that, but how to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All bitmap same time on memory, very heavy.

Maybe you will create bitmap in adapter getview method.
First change your Item class.

```
public class Item{

 public int resourceId;
 public String name;

 public Item(int resourceId, String name){
   this.resourceId = resourceId;
   this.name = name;
 }

}
```

After add to gridArray

```
gridArray.add(new Item(R.drawable.casapoporului, "Casa poporului"));
gridArray.add(new Item(R.drawable.transfagarasan, "Transfagarasan"));
gridArray.add(new Item(R.drawable.transalpina, "Transalpina"));
gridArray.add(new Item(R.drawable.colibita, "Colibita"));
```

And than your adapter' s getView method;

```
public View getView(...){

  int resource = gridArray.get(position).resourceId;
  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                getResources(), resource);
  // imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

}
```

Comment: I understood why. What I didn't understand: The add to gridArray should remain the same in the Galerie.java? Then, my GalerieAdapter is a little bit different in getView method, I updated the first post so you can, please, edit it like it should be edited. (This is the problem - // imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);) Thanks a lot !

Comment: But your in your logcat output error in """ at com.descoper.rom.Galerie.onCreate(Galerie.java:60)"""

Comment: I know that. The problem is that I don't understand how to change the GalerieAdapter. Can you take a look? I have updated the first post. Thanks !